# Debugging for long time in visual studio - I receive a blank web page response in browser

Tags: request, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging, connection-timeout

I need to understand a complex web project and for that I need to be in a debugging session for much longer time. For this I have set the "Application Pool" "Ping Enabled" to False in the IIS 7.5, so that IIS does not terminate itself and I can continue debugging.

But, if I continue debugging for a longer time, I do not receive the response in the browser, rather I receive a blank page. Although there was no exception raised while debugging and everything went properly.

What other configuration is needed to remain in a debugging session for a longer time?

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There are two timeouts that you must consider, both the server and the client.

You have already resolved the server timeout but the client (browser) gives up and shows a white page, usually after 1 minute.

You need to increase the timeout that the browser is willing to wait for.

There are steps to do this in IE here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827